# Fetch Data from same table name across schema

Tags: postgresql

I have this multitenancy database let say of hotels. Each hotel Company is a schema in the database and all have same structure and table names.

Now I want to present menus from all available hotels. Basically I want something like

```
____________________________________________
| schema_name | menu_id | menu_name | cost   |
--------------------------------------------
| hotel_1     | 1       | Ugali     | 4000TZS|
--------------------------------------------
| hotel_2     | 1       | Ugali     | 3500TZS|
--------------------------------------------
| hotel_3     | 1       | Samaki    | 8000TZS|
--------------------------------------------
```

I can get `menu_id`, `menu_name` and `cost` from `menus` tables. How do I achieve that (if it is possible at all) ?

`SET SEARCH_PATH TO hotel_1, hotel_2, hotel_3` does not work and brings results from only one schema.

Comment: You have to write schema names explicitly. `select ... from hotel_1.menu union all select ... from hotel_2.menu `. [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) is more like path variable in os.

Comment: I see. Since we have schemas in the table with query `select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('public', 'information_schema') AND schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%'` is there a way to combine it will menu without manually adding the schema? The Schema keeps changing and adding them manually can become a problem

Comment: After looking about many ways I cannot find another, better way, to do it. Can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is writing your schema names explicitly like below;

```
select menu_id, menu_name, cost from hotel_1.menus
union all
select menu_id, menu_name, cost from hotel_2.menus
union all
select menu_id, menu_name, cost from hotel_3.menus
```

On the other hand, you can write a [set returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) (or [table returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)) and use [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) 
to run dynamic query. Here is a sample set returning function for your case;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_all_menus (
  out menu_id integer,
  out menu_name TEXT,
  out cost DECIMAL(10,2)
)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE
  l_query TEXT;
BEGIN
  -- Create dynamic query
  SELECT
    array_to_string(array_agg(format('select menu_id, menu_name, cost from %I.%I', n.nspname, c.relname)) , E'\nunion all\n')
  INTO
    l_query
  FROM pg_class c
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  WHERE
    c.relkind = 'r' AND
    n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
    n.nspname NOT LIKE '^pg_toast' AND 
    c.relname = 'menus';  --the table name which is common for all schemas 

  --run the query by using execute. 
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE l_query;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER;
```

You can use this function as if its a table. The usage is;

```
select * from get_all_menus();
```

Comment: The function adds great stuffs. Is there easy way to return respective schema too? I tried to add `'SELECT id, departure, destination, n.nspnspname  from %I.%I', n.nspname, c.relname)......` but I get an error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "n"` I have the idea of what the error means but I'm struggling to find where to put that `FROM` clause. I have never done functional Programming with PGS. I did it a lot back in MSSQL Server days

Comment: Try `format('select %L AS schema_name, %L AS table_name, menu_id, menu_name, cost from %I.%I', n.nspname, c.relname, n.nspname, c.relname)`

Comment: That works fine. If I may bother you, can you recommend any good resource for learning Functions with Postgresql, especially for one with MSSQL background in Stored Proc/Functions. It can be text or Video. Thank you for great help!

Comment: I only use PostgreSQL's documentation which is quite good. You may want to check [books](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/books/) list in postgresql.org